# Checking for string in variable fails in twig

Tags: theming, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm working on a twig template for use with a commerce product. Each product has a term applied to it like "Green Ball", "Yellow Ball", "Red Block", and "Purple Block".

I'm trying to take the variable that holds the term, check if it has a string in it, and then use that as the basis for a label. For example if its a Green Ball it would say "Order Ball" and if it was "Red Block" it would say "Order Block".

I'm marking this up based on examples but it always returns false.

```
{% if 'Ball' in product.field_myproduct_type|field_value %} Order Ball {% endif %}
{% if 'Block' in product.field_myproduct_type|field_value %} Order Block {% endif %}
```

I've both tried outputting the variable on its own to confirm the variable is correct and also tried replacing the variable from the conditional with a string to make sure the conditional is the proper syntax and both work as expected. I just can't seem to check in the variable.

I'm doing this from within a twig template that is a variant on commerce-product.twig

Comment: Maybe try `{% if 'ball' in product.field_myproduct_type|field_value|raw|lower %} Order Ball {% endif %}`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe try {{ dump(product.field_myproduct_type|field_value) }} to make sure you are getting a regular string as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Via kint and a bunch of trial and error I identified the right way to do this:

```
{% if 'Ball' in product.field_myproduct_type.0['#plain_text'] %} Order Ball {% endif %}
{% if 'Block' in product.field_myproduct_type.0['#plain_text'] %} Order Block {% endif %}
```

Thank you 100pic for your assistance.